# бинарные операции си

Tags: c, битовые-операции, arm, stm32

Как записать переменную вида B00110011 и потом разложить на переменные (то есть на отдельные единицы и нули)?

Comment: сохраняя остатки от деления на 2 и деля на 2 (или сдвигая вправо на бит, что одно и то же), в цикле.

Comment: В чем важность "бинарных операций"? Почему это вынесено в заголовок?

Comment: Еще может быть полезно посмотреть в сторону битовых полей. Ну если новенький, то, возможно, откроете для себя новую структуру данных

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вы имеете в виду что-то вроде этого.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void split_to_bits( int a[], unsigned char value )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = ( ( 1u << ( CHAR_BIT - i - 1 ) ) & value ) != 0; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int bits[CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

    split_to_bits( bits, 0b00110011 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++ ) printf( "%d ", bits[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Цикл `for` можно переписать также в виде

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++ )
{
    a[CHAR_BIT - i - 1] = value % 2;
    value >>= 1;
}
```